# how can i take speech recognition in hear.py and put it in a entry box in tkinter chatbot_gui.py?

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, chatbot

file name is hear, `Lquery = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()` is varible form the sr function listen.

```
self.msg_entry=Entry(bottom_label,bg="#2C3E50",fg=TEXT_COLOR,font=FONT)
self.msg_entry.focus()
self.msg_entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_enter)
```

```
#send button which will call on_enter function to send the query
send_button=Button(bottom_label,text="Send",font=FONT_BOLD,width=8,bg="Green",command=lambda: self.on_enter(None))
send_button.place(relx=0.80,rely=0.008,relheight=0.06,relwidth=0.20)
```

I tried adding: `self.msg_entry.insert(0, env.hear.Lquery)`

I tried adding a third file env. that imports both import hear.py and import chatbot_gui.py(trying to avoid the circular dependency (but it doesn't work)
I tried to write from hear.py (chatbot is the class) `add_bot(function)`. `cb().add_bot().msg.entry.insert(END,keyboard.write(Lquery))`...which tells me add_bot is a None type and has no attribute msg_entry.
I tried a million other things.
I need to add `hear.listen()` to Chatbot_gui.py for sr

Just can't get anything to work.  The gui should accept keyboard input as well as voice.

Comment: bottom_label.place(relwidth=1,rely=0.825) the line above .  the app runs ok, I just can't convert it to speech.